# How to assemble x86 assembly on MacOS?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86

I am having trouble assembling x86 asm code on my Mac. More specifically, I am getting errors. However, when I assemble the exact same source code on my Linux computer, it works.

My situation:

- I am using an Intel Mac
- the syntax in AT&T
- I have gcc installed
- I have the GNU assembler extension installed on in VS Code

I tried using the following commands:
`as -maximum.s -o maximum.o`
and
`gcc -c maximum.s -o maximum.o`

In both situations, I got the same error:

```
maximum.s:1:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .data
              ^
maximum.s:5:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
              ^
```

I highly doubt there is anything wrong with my source code since it assembled fine on Linux. But here is my full source code anyway:

```
.section .data
    data_items:
        .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi, 4), %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx

start_loop:
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit
    incl %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi, 4), %eax
    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jle start_loop

    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop

loop_exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Thank you

Comment: Well `eax=1` / `int $0x80` certainly isn't going to work on macOS, that's the Linux 32-bit ABI and call number.  Older macOS did support 32-bit x86 processes, unlike current macOS where 64-bit code is the only option.  32-bit macOS code could use `int $0x80` with args on the stack (FreeBSD style) other than the call number in EAX, but I think different call numbers.

Comment: I think macOS also uses different section names; **check a macOS tutorial**.  Unless there's a weird line-ending problem (which wouldn't make sense if the same file assembles on Linux), I don't see anything wrong with the actual syntax.

Comment: @Rob: This is GAS syntax.  `as` and `gcc` on macOS are probably both `clang` in disguise unless they installed actual GNU Binutils and GCC, but they use the same syntax as GAS uses everywhere:   https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be an example from [Programming from the Ground Up: Chapter 3: Your First Programs](http://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/2007/01/chapter-3-your-first-programs.html?m=1), where the author is illustrating “the process for writing and building *Linux* assembly-language programs” (emphasis added). Unfortunately, when assembling this on macOS, a few changes may be necessary:

- The “unexpected token in '.section' directive” error is because macOS `as` does not understand the `.section .data` syntax. It is just `.data`.
- This uses 32-bit absolute addressing, but contemporary macOS versions are 64-bit. Note use of `leaq` below.
- This is using the Linux `int $0x80` to exit. In macOS, the equivalent is a `syscall` of `$0x2000001`.

Thus, you might end up with something like:

```
.data
    data_items:
        .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.text
.globl _main

_main:
    movq $0, %rbx                # maximum in rbx
    movq $0, %rcx                # index in rcx
    leaq data_items(%rip), %rsi  # Load the address of data_items into %rsi

start_loop:
    movl (%rsi, %rcx, 4), %eax   # Load the value pointed to by si, offset by cx, into ax

    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit

    incq %rcx

    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jle start_loop

    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop

loop_exit:
    movq %rbx, %rdi              # return code in rdi
    movq $0x2000001, %rax        # 0x2000001 is the exit syscall number on macOS
    syscall
```

```
$ as --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ as -o maximum.o maximum.s

$ ld -o maximum maximum.o

$ ./maximum

$ echo $?
222
```

---

FWIW, note that I used `_main` instead of `_start`. If you really want to use `_start`, you can specify that while linking, e.g.,

```
ld -o maximum maximum.o -e _start
```

For a few random examples illustrating `_main` vs `_start`, see [this](https://retrocoding.net/hello-world-in-x8664-assembly-on-linux-and-macos), or [this](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/), or [this](https://sigridjin.medium.com/running-apple-m1-assembly-with-hello-world-program-172ec9ae66e7), or [this](https://rida.foo/posts/debugging-x86-assembly-on-modern-macos/), or [this](https://kokkonisd.github.io/2019/07/22/x86-assembly-on-osx/).

In the comments below, it has been noted that there might be more robust patterns for macOS assembly, entailing the use of a C Runtime (CRT) object (which will affect the entry point in the above), avoiding raw `syscall`, etc. Also, see Apple’s [Writing 64-bit Intel code for Apple Platforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-64-bit-intel-code-for-apple-platforms).

All of that having been said, the original author’s attempt was to provide a minimalist example of a Linux assembly program. And I have attempted to restrict myself to the most minimalist changes to get that to run on macOS.

Comment: IIRC the entry point on macOS is just `start`, no underscore.

Comment: `_main` is the symbol corresponding to the main function.  It's what the CRT startup code calls. However, this is not the first thing that runs in your program.  That would be the CRT startup code itself, which starts at label `start`.  If you read the `ld` man page, you'll find that the entry point indeed defaults to `start`.

Comment: Again: `_main` is the main function.  Tutorials that use it usually link with the C runtime, which provides the actual entrypoint.  That entrypoint then calls `_main`.  You can of course specify any name you want with `-e`, but `start` is the default.  Have you considered that the random tutorials you linked may just not follow the default conventions on macOS, instead trying to apply ELF conventions?  ELF is so common, it's easy to forget that ELF differs from other conventions in how symbols are named and decorated.

Comment: For reference, here is Apple's own [CRT entry stub](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Csu/Csu-88/start.s).  See how the symbol is named `start`?  The tutorials are just unidiomatic, written by people who know about how ELF works, but not Mach-O.

Comment: Recommend the tutorials that start at `_main`, start using the CRT stub (i.e. no `-e _main`) and use libc functions to interact with the system.  Not using the CRT stub is unidiomatic and doing raw syscalls yourself is unidiomatic, too.